# Addtional QFT Book synergetic to Srednicki. Differences $\phi^4$ and $\phi^3$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral

I currently hear a course to basic QFT in path integral formulation. Focus is on few and elementary particles, not on many body systems. The lecturer follows the book of Srednicki, which therefore roughly contains what I need to know. Sadly I do not like the book to much, it is not precise nor vivid. Does somebody know a good synergetic book?
I thought about the book of Zee, though I heard he uses a $\phi^4$ formulation, while Sredicki works with $\phi^3$. Sadly I do not know too much about how relevant the differences are for learning the principles and if this is going to be a problem. I still need to mainly follow the Srednicki.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by phi^4 and phi^3 formulation? QFT is a theory on the quantum fields. It is mainly about a large amount of concepts and technique and should not limited on one specific lagrangian.

Comment: I think almost nobody does the $\phi^3$ theory in detail, except Srednicki.

Comment: Hi Zorakh, Res. recom. questions are restricted on Phys.SE because they tend to be _primarily opinion-based_ list questions. I'm closing this list question as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

**A great QFT textbook**

Peskin ; Shroeder - Quantum Field Theory

**An amazing QFT textbook**

Tom Lancaster - QFT for the gifted amateur